# PHP image cropping rotates image

Tags: php

I'm creating a mobile app that allows people to upload photos, but I have a problem resizing the images with the Image Manipulator Class you can find here https://gist.github.com/philBrown/880506.

My problem is that when I take a photo by keeping my phone in portrait mode, the image is being rotated 90 degrees to the right. When I take a photo in  landscape mode, everything goes fine.

Here's my cropping PHP code:

```
$manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);
$width  = $manipulator->getWidth();
$height = $manipulator->getHeight();
$centreX = round($width / 2);
$centreY = round($height / 2);

// our dimensions will be 600x450
$x1 = $centreX - 300; // 600 / 2
$y1 = $centreY - 225; // 450 / 2

$x2 = $centreX + 300; // 600 / 2
$y2 = $centreY + 225; // 450 / 2

// center cropping to 600x450
$newImage = $manipulator->crop($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);

// rotate 90 degrees to the right
$imageResource = $newImage->getResource();
$angle = '90'; // in degrees
$fileName = "../file_upload_img/43/" . $random_file_name . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"];
$rotatedImage = imagerotate($imageResource, $angle);
imagejpeg($rotatedImage, $fileName, 95);

// saving file to uploads folder
$manipulator->save("../file_upload_img/43/" . $random_file_name . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]);
```

How can I make sure that photos taken in portrait mode don't get rotated when cropped?

EDIT*

The upload.php code:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../includes/ImageManipulator.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../init/db/conn.php');

ob_start();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);

echo "</pre>";

print_r("file type: " . $_FILES["Filedata"]["type"]);

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["Filedata"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["Filedata"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["Filedata"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["Filedata"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["Filedata"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["Filedata"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["Filedata"]["size"] < 9999999999)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        if ($_FILES["Filedata"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["Filedata"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["Filedata"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["Filedata"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("../file_upload_img/" . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else {
            $random_file_name = sha1(uniqid($_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]));

            /*
            * ROTATE, CROP AND RESIZE
            */
            // 4:3 Ratio version
            $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);

            // Resize image to 600px wide and 450px high
            $manipulator = $manipulator->resample(600, 450);    

            // saving file to uploads folder
            $manipulator->save("../file_upload_img/43/" . $random_file_name . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]);

            $width  = $manipulator->getWidth();
            $height = $manipulator->getHeight();
            $centreX = round($width / 2);
            $centreY = round($height / 2);
            // our dimensions will be 600x450
            $x1 = $centreX - 300; // 600 / 2
            $y1 = $centreY - 225; // 450 / 2

            $x2 = $centreX + 300; // 600 / 2
            $y2 = $centreY + 225; // 450 / 2

            // center cropping to 200x130
            $newImage = $manipulator->crop($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);

            // rotate 90 degrees to the right
            $imageResource = $newImage->getResource();
            $angle = '90'; // in degrees
            $fileName = "../file_upload_img/43/" . $random_file_name . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"];
            $rotatedImage = imagerotate($imageResource, $angle);
            imagejpeg($rotatedImage, $fileName, 95);

            // saving file to uploads folder
            $manipulator->save("../file_upload_img/43/" . $random_file_name . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]);

            // 640:120 Ratio version
            $manipulator_640 = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);

            // Resize image to 640px wide and 120px high
            $manipulator_640 = $manipulator_640->resample(640, 120);    

            // saving file to uploads folder
            $manipulator_640->save("../file_upload_img/header/" . $random_file_name . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]);

            $width_640  = $manipulator_640->getWidth();
            $height_640 = $manipulator_640->getHeight();
            $centreX_640 = round($width_640 / 2);
            $centreY_640 = round($height_640 / 2);
            // our dimensions will be 640x120
            $x1_640 = $centreX_640 - 320; // 640 / 2
            $y1_640 = $centreY_640 - 60; // 120 / 2

            $x2_640 = $centreX_640 + 320; // 640 / 2
            $y2_640 = $centreY_640 + 60; // 120 / 2

            // center cropping to 640x120
            $newImage_640 = $manipulator_640->crop($x1_640, $y1_640, $x2_640, $y2_640);
            // saving file to uploads folder
            $manipulator_640->save("../file_upload_img/header/" . $random_file_name . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]);
            /*
            *****************
            */
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}

$data=ob_get_clean();
```

EDIT 2

I've have added the code from user @matewka to my PHP. I've edited my PHP with the rotating code included. The code doesn't rotate the images at all.

Comment: I guess your phone is rotating the _preview_ of the image taken in _portrait_ orientation, __not__ the image itself. Many other devices might also be able to do this. So you're always looking at the properly rotated image but when you push it to the `ImageManipulator` it doesn't pay any attention whether the image is rotated because this information is held somewhere in meta-data.

What you need is to look for some meta-data which would indicate that the image is rotated or not. That's my guess.

Comment: Well, the uploaded image is rotated on my server, so it does rotate the image itself.

Comment: How can you tell it is rotated? How do you preview it?

Comment: My phone takes the image and it looks normal. You know what it looks like to take a photo with your phone in portrait mode right? That's what I see. But when I look at the photo on the server (the photo I just took is directly uploaded to the server and cropped), it's been cropped, but also rotated 90 degrees to the left. So the preview looks okay, but the photo on the server is rotated.

Comment: @matewka I just realized that the phone itself has already rotated the image after I took it. How can I rotate recently taken images by my phone so they look normal?

Comment: I asked for a way, not the cause, so I don't see why it's 'a different question' for you...

Comment: There's no solution on the web, only people addressing the issue. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your recent comment:

> *I just realized that the phone itself has already rotated the image after I took it. **How can I rotate recently taken images by my phone so they look normal?***

to rotate an image in PHP you can use [imagerotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) function. So, right after you cropped the image and saved it to the `$newImage` variable, proceed with those operations:

```
$imageResource = $newImage->getResource();
$angle = '90'; // in degrees
$fileName = "../file_upload_img/43/" . $random_file_name . $_FILES["Filedata"]["name"];
$rotatedImage = imagerotate($imageResource, $angle);
imagejpeg($rotatedImage, $fileName, 95);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to rotate the image before the crop, not after it. I crop an image to a size of 600X450. If I crop and rotate after cropping, the dimensions will become 450X600. So how do I modify your code to rotate before the cropping and rotating?

Comment: @user3608176, what is the difference? Let's say your original image is 1200X900. If you rotate it, it will become 900X1200. Then you crop it and you get 450X600 - the same as the other way. Those 2 operations are convertible. No matter in what order you perform them, the result will be always the same.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry :) Thank you, I will try this out right away and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Fix the image orientation using `exif_read_data`

```
function orientation($path){
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
    $exif = exif_read_data($path);
    $orientation = $exif['COMPUTED']['Orientation'];
    switch ($orientation) {
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image, 180, 0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image, -90, 0);
            break;
        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
            break;
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $path);
}
```

There may be 4 possible orientations to be detected [[Here]](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html)